# LaTeX - Unwanted space above horizontal line

Tags: latex

I am forced to choose between two things, but I want both.

What I want to type is something like this:

```
Name of a list
------------- horizontal line
- Item A
- Item B
- Item B
```

I am able to do that with the following code:

```
\textbf{Name of a list}: \\
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} 
- Item A \\
- Item B  \\
- Item C \\
```

Here is the result:
[image]

This is all good so far. Now, say I want the spacing between the different list items to be double spacing. The `\doublespacing`  command. i.e. I wrote:

```
\textbf{Name of a list}: \\
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\doublespacing
- Item A \\
- Item B  \\
- Item C \\
```

The problem is, when I do that, the space between "Name of a list" and horizontal line below it become double spaced as well, and I can not get rid of that unwanted space.
And here is the result of that:
[image]

It's subtle, but you can definitely see that there is more space between them now.

How do I get rid of that space?
And on a related note, even if I do not want the double spacing between the different items in the list, how can I eliminate the space between "Name of a list" and the horizontal line bellow it? I want them to be really close to each other. Is that possible?

Edit: I am sorry for the unclear code. Here is the full code I used:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}

\textbf{Name of a list}: \\ 
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} 
\doublespacing 
- A \\
- B \\
- C \\


\end{flushleft}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: I am sorry, I added the full code now.

Comment: Do you mean `flushleft` instead of `fleshleft`?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about that.

Comment: place \doublespacing after first item and remove \doublespacing at the begining

Comment: I actually did try that but it didn't work...

Comment: Please check the answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\doublespacing starts from the position it is placed. If you want only the some portion of document enclose it with in \begin{doublesapce} and \end{doublesapce}

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\textbf{Name of a list}: \\
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
- A \\
\begin{doublespace}
- B \\
- C \\
\end{doublespace}

\end{flushleft}


 \end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! If its not bothersome, about my other question... 

Answer (score 2):

- don't use `\\` to get a new line. In almost all cases (with the exception of tables) this is just wrong and will lead to underfull hboxes. If you need to start a new line, simply leave an empty line in your source code, this will be interpreted as new paragraph
- instead of manually creating an itemization, you can simply let latex do it for you by using an itemize environment. The item automatically have some vertical space between them, so you don't need the double spacing at all. If you prefer `-` instead of the default bullet points, you can change it with the `enumitem` package

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}

\textbf{Name of a list}:
\vspace{-1ex}% <- adjust here the space between text and your line

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} 

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,label={-},topsep=0pt]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much. I just started learning LaTeX the other day, so tips like these are really useful.

Comment: @Aziz Oh, if you just start learning, I can recommend https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/ (the book is also available as free pdf on the website)